# Omnetpp and Inet 4: Run LEACH protcole

Tags: simulation, iot, omnet++, network-protocols, inet

I am trying to run leach protocol as described in [LEACH](https://github.com/Agr-IoT/LEACH) without success. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!!!

[image: The error console here]

I reinstall it by fellowing the descriptions provided [this linlk](https://github.com/Agr-IoT/LEACH) and I still get the same error. I expected to succefully run it.

Comment: Are you running INET version 4.2.5? 
That's the version the model has been tested on

Comment: @NuwanJayawardene, Yes, I followed the instructions to the letter.  OMNeT++ version 5.6.2 and INET Framework version 4.2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you link the LEACH3 project with the INET directory?

> Link it with INET using `properties > project references` and ticking on the inet option.

The window that opens looks like this:

[image: screenshot of project project properties window]

You have to rebuild the LEACH3 project once again after linking.

Comment: Thanks, @Nuwan Jayawardene, this problem is solved by following your instructions. 
Actually, I got another error.  

Error: Cannot load library 'libLEACH3.so': libLEACH3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

End.